# Main shape not displaying like the others in object mode

Tags: object-mode

The body of this worm project started displaying with no detail. How can I get it to display grey again like the others?

(I only use blender for making 3D print files. No rendering or color needed)

[image]

Comment: can you provide blend file?

Comment: I think you probably set the viewport display settings to metallic and black, or you’ve inverted your normals. Check that.

Comment: check the normals direction - "Face Orientation" under Viewport Overlays

Comment: @chris https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pyB4t3L3F9iym2lQzBS89gavGmmLKNhZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for the comments all, again, mostly use blender for cutting up large STL files and making minor tweaks. So stumbling through a lot of this. But, I think I correctly flipped the normals and tried the display settings change without getting the grey color back. Will try more  thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Zargul already mentioned, you flipped your normals. You can check this here by checking "face orientation":

[image]

Red means: wrong orientation.

So press "Tab" to start edit mode, then press "A" to select all, then mesh -> normals -> recalculate outside

[image]

Then it looks like this (blue as it should)

[image]

then uncheck the face orientation again.

then you get:

[image]

still a bit dark but better,

then choose matcap -> textured and you get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Chris. And thanks for being patient, I'm a newb! Was able to get it looking how you have it. Still curious though, why cant it display with the same kind of grey as the eyes and holes? Thats how it was before I goofed up whatever I did.

Comment: I did separate the original file into several pieces with "L" & "P" in edit mode. And just tried splitting it further. (Eye lids separate from body) Still looks same. Could doing stuff like that have caused it?

Comment: No, I don’t think so. Maybe - but just an assumption - because your geometry is so dense.

Comment: OK , thanks again for taking a look.